# iOS 9 pop view that was pushed from storyboard reference

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, storyboard-reference

I am working with `xCode 8.2` `iOS 9` with `Swift 3.0`. I have created a `storyboard reference` in my Main storyboard to refer to a view controller in another storyboard in the code.

When I was creating a segue from the source VC to the destination, it showed these options:

[image]

no `Relationship Segue` section is shown as mentioned [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-9-staying-organized-with-storyboard-references--cms-24226)

Why it is not shown and is there a way to show it?
Also, how can I go back to the caller VC in Main storyboard from the callee VC in the secondary storyboard? I have tried to use `popViewController` but it doesn't work.